# Debug android application with break point in Runnable [Android Studio]

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, breakpoints, runnable

I need to debug my application and debug the code is part of `Runnable` and do some actions in application then debug the code again, but I can't do it, I can't do any actions as debug point is fired immediately.

code :

```
public class UpdateHandler {

    public static Handler getHandler() {
        if (sHandler == null) {
            HandlerThread looper = new HandlerThread("update Handler");
            looper.start();
            sHandler = new Handler(looper.getLooper());
        }

        return sHandler;
    }
}


UpdateHandler.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        update();
    }
});

public void update() {
    // i put the debug point here .
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For runnables/async tasks etc it is useful to call `Debug.waitForDebugger()`, **prior** the code you set the breakpoint on:

```
...
Debug.waitForDebugger();
foo.bar();               # breakpoint on this line
...
```